# Updating database record through link in email for Rails 3

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, email

My app sends out reminder emails and in each of these emails I'd like to include a link for the user to click that would update a record in the database.

I don't think I want this tied in through a controller, as that would then push this 'request' from the email link to a view of some sort in the browser.

Is there any way to accomplish this without a controller handling the 'request'?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the user to follow a link that leads to a view and updates one or more attributes in the database.

Rails is built around the Model-View-Controller principle. A request is taken from the Rails router and handed over to the corresponding controller and action. The controller does the job, invokes the model (that queries the database) and then hands over to the view. A view is for displaying data, not for working with data and never updates anything in the model!

In your case: your link should lead to a controller/action where you do the update of your record and then display a view.

Comment: thx for the reply. What you mention is my understanding of MVC. What I'm hoping to accomplish is not having to display a view. The link in the email would include a token that would distinguish which table record to update. No need to display anything to the user - they probably won't even be logged into the webapp at the time.

Comment: You can just render nothing or just return head, see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: yeah - I'm better off displaying some sort of message to the user after the update, rather than a blank page. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Sure. It is all at your fingertips. Render nothing, return head or render a beautiful view :)
[Please accept the answer if it was the answer you were looking for...]

Comment: well, it's not the answer I was hoping for ;) - I'd much rather just be able to update the db with the link in the email, and not have to produce a view (whether it is a blank page, return head, or a beautiful view). However, given the lack of any other answers that would help me do that, I'm assuming it can't be done, and hence, you deserve the 'accept' for the answer.

Comment: In fact, returning head:ok is not really rendering a view, therefore you get what you want :)